# Create Notification for API 10

Tags: android, notifications

I want to create a notification for API 10. This is my function:

```
public void showNotificationCombat(Context context) {


    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, Pin.class), 0);

    Notification noti =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Hello World!")
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent).build();

    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = 
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, noti);
}
```

I didn't get any error inside Eclipse, but my app crashed at this point... I don't know what why.. Everything looks ok!

Answer (score 0):

this method supports Notifications in all API´s, using [**NotificationManager.**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html)

```
public  void createNotification(long when, String notificationTitle, String notificationContent, String notificationUrl, Context ctx){
    try{
        Intent notificationIntent;  
        if("".equals(notificationTitle)){
            notificationTitle = ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        }
        /*large icon for notification,normally use App icon*/
        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        int smalIcon =R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        /*create intent for show notification details when user clicks notification*/
        if(!"".equals(notificationUrl)){
            notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW ,Uri.parse(notificationUrl));    
        }
        else{
          //Intent to load Pin.class
            notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Pin.class);
        }           
        /*create new task for each notification with pending intent so we set Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK */
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        /*get the system service that manage notification NotificationManager*/
        NotificationManager notificationManager =(NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 

        /*build the notification*/
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
        .setWhen(when)
        .setContentText(notificationContent)
        .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
        .setSmallIcon(smalIcon)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setTicker(notificationTitle)
        .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)        
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        /*sending notification to system.Here we use unique id (when)for making different each notification
         * if we use same id,then first notification replace by the last notification*/
        notificationManager.notify((int) when, notificationBuilder.build()); 
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("NotificationManager", "createNotification::" + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

This is an example how to create a notification to load Pin Activity.

```
  createNotification(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()," my app","click to load Pin.class","",getApplicationContext());
```

And yes you can add sound to your notification, here´s another example:

```
private void displayNotification(String msg)
{
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    int ID = 12;
    Intent i = new Intent(context, Pin.class);
    i.putExtra("ID", ID);
    i.putExtra("msg",msg);
    PendingIntent pendInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i, 0);
    Notification notif = new Notification(0,"Hey!, Jorgesys you have a new new Message",System.currentTimeMillis());
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Message", msg, pendInt);     
    notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notif.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;     
    notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND |  Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;          
    notif.ledARGB = Color.WHITE;
    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    notif.ledOnMS = 5000;                         
    notif.ledOffMS = 5000;      
    nm.notify(ID, notif);
}
```

Comment: What is notificationUrl parameter? I want when the user clicks on the notification to go on Pin.class Activity... What value I will put on notificationUrl?

Comment: use empty string ( "" ), but if want to open an Url  when your notification is clicked, define an url.

Comment: Where I must add code (and what code) when the user clicked the notification to run Activity Pin.class?

Comment: OK! I found it! Thanks! a lot!

Comment: I have edited my answer, you only need to create the intent to load Pin Activity. :

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to add Default Sound to my notification? and Vibrate?

Comment: Yes, see the displayNotification() method, of my answer.